# extract data from sscanf

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am wondering why sscanf does not work correctly. Here is the case

I have a string "1,2,3,#" and I want to extract the data without comma, the code is

```
int a1,a2,a3;
char s;
string teststr = "1,2,3,#";
sscanf(teststr.c_str(), "%d,%d,%d,%s",&a1,&a2,&a3,&s);
cout << teststr << endl;
cout << a1 << a2 << a3 << s << endl;
```

the expected output should be `123#`, but the real result I got is `120#` that `a3` is always 0.

If I expand to 4 numbers,

```
int a1,a2,a3,a4;
char s;
string teststr = "1,2,3,4,#";
sscanf(teststr.c_str(), "%d,%d,%d,%d,%s",&a1,&a2,&a3,&a4,&s);
cout << teststr << endl;
cout << a1 << a2 << a3 << a4 << s << endl;
```

Then the result becomes `1230#`.
It seems like the last int is always 0. 
Why will this happen? How to fix it?

Comment: `"%d,%d,%d,%s"` --> `"%d,%d,%d,%c"`

Comment: Thanks! That works! But why?

Comment: If the actual type of the argument with the format parameter does not match the UB. `%s` add the NUL (`'\0'`) so it will  destroy(rewirte) the memory. or should be `char s[2];`... `%1s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sscanf(teststr.c_str(), "%d,%d,%d,%s",&a1,&a2,&a3,&s);
                                   ^  passing char variable s to %s (specifier for reading single char is %c not %s)
```

Instead try this -

```
sscanf(teststr.c_str(), "%d,%d,%d,%c",&a1,&a2,&a3,&s);
```